# How to instantly recognize in which CRS my .tif file is?

Tags: python, metadata, projection, qgis

I am currently working with a tif file that I have issues understanding. Its metadata is:

```
driver GTiff
dtype float32
nodata -9999.0
width 523
height 582
count 1
crs PROJCS["WGS_1984_EPSG_Alaska_Polar_Stereographic",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Stereographic"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",90],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-150],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.994],PARAMETER["false_easting",2000000],PARAMETER["false_northing",2000000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
transform | 125.52, 0.00, 2522546.90|
| 0.00,-125.52,-1317885.15|
| 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|
Data minimum, maximum =  -9999.0 1557.6232
```

If I open it on QGIS the CRS is unknown, and I never know which `AUTHORITY` argument describes the CRS of my tif. Do you have a method to know which CRS is governing a tif, amongst all the EPSG stated its metadata ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can usually search on http://epsg.io - which in this case finds [EPSG:5936](https://epsg.io/5936).